# List comprehension for tuple containing nested lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have am struggling to get a list comprehension to work on the following data structure, which is a tuple containing a list and a list of dictionaries, from which I only want to return the list with the dictionaries in:

```
([[1,2,3,4], [{"foo1":1,"bar1":2,"foobar1":3},{"foo2":1,"bar2":2,"foobar2":3}]])
```

Where the above is assigned to the variable `var`, I have so far tried the following list comprehension, which is not doing what I want:

```
var = [[x] for x in var]
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: what you mean about `want to return the list with the dictionaries` ?

Comment: @kasra yes that is what i want.

Comment: I think what @Kasra is saying is that we don't know what you mean by that... can you provide example output at least?

Comment: Doesn't var[1] do just that?

Answer (score 1):

Here we go

```
>>> var = ([[1,2,3,4], [{"foo1":1,"bar1":2,"foobar1":3},{"foo2":1,"bar2":2,"foobar2":3}]])
>>> [j for i in var for j in i if isinstance(j, dict)]
[{'bar1': 2, 'foobar1': 3, 'foo1': 1}, {'foobar2': 3, 'bar2': 2, 'foo2': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using var[1] gets the list of dictionaries from the tuple:

```
>>> var = ([[1,2,3,4], [{"foo1":1,"bar1":2,"foobar1":3},{"foo2":1,"bar2":2,"foobar2":3}]])
>>> var[1] 
[{'bar1': 2, 'foo1': 1, 'foobar1': 3}, {'bar2': 2, 'foo2': 1, 'foobar2': 3}]
```